# How to do laravel form validation distinct with condition

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have array inputs of order and products

```
['inputs'][0]['order_id']
['inputs'][0]['product_id']
```

I need to validate if the inputs have same **order_id** then no duplicate **product_id** is allowed
Currently i'm using the distinct validation method like so :

```
'items.*.order_id' => 'required',
'items.*.product_id' => ['required', 'distinct:strict']
```

but it seems that even the **order_id** is diffferent it will still givng the validation error if the **product_id** have duplicated

i'm confuse how to add the conditional clause above, to achieve the expected result

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to create a custom validation rule, in which you can write your own logic to decide whether the input is valid.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

If you scroll down a bit you'll come to the section on data aware rules. Sounds like this might be a useful approach for you.